# Python datetime.striptime error - parse time string to time object

Tags: python, datetime

Trying to parse time string into a time object and get the time difference with the current time.

Here is the example:

```
>>> user_reg_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("20091129060140", "%Y%M%d%H%m%S")
>>> user_reg_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("20140404134026", "%Y%M%d%H%m%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 6
```

notice that when the time string is `20091129060140` no error but when the time string is `20140404134026` I get the above error. Except the date there is nothing different between time string (such as length). How could this be even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have flipped the %m and the %M, it should be as follows:

`%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

for both.

`%m` is the month (01 - 12) and `%M` is the minutes (00-59)

Here is the correct code:

```
user_reg_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("20091129060140", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
user_reg_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("20140404134026", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, It is easy to get confused with all these similar looking symbols. :)

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, Yeah woops. I approved the edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, using [python-dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c).

```
In [1]: from dateutil import parser

In [2]: parser.parse('20091129060140')
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 29, 6, 1, 40)

In [3]: parser.parse('20140404134026')                                                                            
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 4, 13, 40, 26)
```